# Why do I need to use async/await twice in node-postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise, node-postgres

I wrote this code that seems to be working:

database.js

```
const {Pool} = require('pg');

const pool = new Pool({
connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
});

module.exports = {
query: (text, params) => pool.query(text, params)
};
```

auth_facade.js

```
const database = require('../../utils/database');

module.exports.findPersonByEmail = async function(email) {
const query = 'SELECT * FROM Person WHERE email = $1';
const values = [email];

try {
    console.log(1);
    const {rows} = await database.query(query, values);
    console.log(2);
    return rows[0];
} catch (err) {
    next(err);
}
};
```

auth_controller.js

```
const authFacade = require('./auth_facade');

module.exports.signin = async function(req, res, next) {
console.log(0);
var person = await authFacade.findPersonByEmail(req.body.email);
console.log(3);
};
```

It shows, as I expected, 0123.

However, I don't understand why I need the `async/await` on both `auth_facade::findPersonByEmail` and `auth_controller::signin`?

Why, if I remove the async from `auth_controller::signin` signature and the `await` inside it, I don't get 0123 anymore, but 0132 instead? Shouldn't it be blocked anyway be the await in `auth_facade`?

Comment: You don't need `async/await` in your `signin` function, if all it does is to call `authFacade.findPersonByEmail`; otherwise, you "need" it because the underlying `pool.query` returns a promise (so it's `async`). `authFacade.findPersonByEmail` is `async`, so it's not blocking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code:

A family goes to a mall. (0) Dad is tired and says "Go ahead do some shopping, I'll wait then we'll all go home together." (1) A little later daughter says "I don't feel like going into that shop, I'll just hang out here, waiting for you, and then we'll go back to Dad." (2) Mom finishes shopping and returns to daughter, (3) they both come back to pick up Dad and all go home together.

Your code without the outer `await`:

A family goes to a mall. (0) Dad is tired and says "Go ahead do some shopping, I'll be here." (1) A little later daughter says "I don't feel like going into that shop, I'll just hang out here, waiting for you, and then we'll go back to Dad." However, at about the same time, (3) Dad turns around and decides to go home, because waiting is for losers. (2) Mom finishes shopping and returns to daughter, they both come back to find Dad is gone with the car and they're stuck in the mall with a bunch of shopping bags.

Both daughter and Dad need to wait in order for them not to leave someone behind.

Comment: Great explanation. My next question is "is there a way for me to avoid only one await/async?" The only asynchronous task in my mind should be the database query. In otherwords, can I force dad to follow his daughter, and wait with her in front of the shop for the mother?

Comment: Actually you can. Taking Dad with you is the equivalent of what @woozyking said: `signin` doesn't need to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you need `await` in two places, `AuthFacade` and `AuthController`, is because you're dealing with *two different* Promises:

1. one *in* `findPersonByEmail()` (from DB query)
2. one *from* `findPersonByEmail()`.

Shown:

```
findPersonByEmail(email: string): Promise<Person>;

//same difference
let person = await authFacade.findPersonByEmail(req.body.email);

//same difference
authFacade.findPersonByEmail(req.body.email).then(person => {
});
```

If you'd like to learn more, please read: [Up and Running with Asynchronous JavaScript](https://medium.com/@rcepeda1993/async-js-the-complete-guide-670b4cf906c6).